# Why can only admins see additional fields in Approval Request detail screen?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, approval-process

In Lightning when an approver clicks on one of the "Items To Approve", he is taken to the Approval Request detail screen. Here it shows approval status and just two fields: Name and Lead Owner.

[image]

However, in my approval process I have added many other fields to the approval layout and if I'm logged in as an admin, I see all of those fields, but any other profile cannot. This is true even though those users have access to those fields and can see them on regular page layouts.

Why can only admins see additional fields in Approval Request detail screen?

Are there any other settings I need to check, or should I open a case with Salesforce as the feature is not behaving as expected?

Comment: Do you have more than one approval process for this object?

Comment: I have only one active, and 2 inactive.